# Remove a substring from a string in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am writing a jQuery function on the click event of a checkbox list, which stores the value in a string when one item is checked and it removes the string when it is unchecked. I am taking the closed label text and insert and remove it from the string. I can add the strings but I am not able to remove it.

Here is my code:

```
var currentage = '';

$('#<%=chk_ange.ClientID%> input:checkbox').click(function () {
    var str = $(this).next('label').text();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if (currentage.indexOf($(this).next('label').text()) == -1) {
            currentage = currentage + str;
        }
        alert('checked' + currentage);
    }
    else {
        currentage.replace(str, "Hello");
        //currentage.replace(str, 'None');
        alert('unchecked' + currentage);
    } 
}
```

I am storing the values in a global variable so that i can compare the value in each click.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign the result of `replace` back to your variable like:

```
currentage = currentage.replace(str, "Hello");
```

See: [String.prototype.replace() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: ohh that was the mistake thanks for the quick response solved...sometime it just goes off from the eyesight...

Comment: @user2664298, yeah that happens :) , You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to equal the result from `currentage.replace(str, "Hello");` to `currentage`. String are immutable so the `replace()`function returns a new modified string.

```
currentage = currentage.replace(str, "Hello");
```